# What and where is the pre-compiled header file in an xcode project?

Tags: ios, xcode, citrix

QUESTION: What and where is the `pre-compiled header file` in an xcode project?

PROBLEM: I need help with xcode.

DISCLAIMER: I know nothing about xcode.

BACKSTORY: I have an app built with appcelerator, which builds an xcode project for me. Now I want to make it Citrix Ready which by this press release should be easy http://www.appcelerator.com/press-releases/citrix/ but < rant > they have no documentation on this, no one at appcelerator seems to care, and they say to use SO for support (which I did and it got me the peer pressure badge, yay!).< /rant >

So, since they suck I'm trying to do it myself directly in xcode and with a question that is acceptable within SO guidelines.

SITUATION: I'm up to step 3 of the steps to do this are listed on the Citrix website: http://docs.citrix.com/en-us/mdx-toolkit/10/xmob-mdx-dev-guide-overview/xmob-mdx-dev-ios-apps.html#par_anchortitle_33e5

*Step 3: Revise a line of code in the pre-compiled header file in the app project to import WorxEnable.h from Worx.framework as shown in the following example*

```
#ifdef__OBJC__
_
//import MDX extensions
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <SystemConfiguration/SCNetworkReachability.h>
#import <Worx/WorxEnable.h>
#endif
```

I just don't know what or where the `pre-compiled header file` is.

Any help would be much appreciated.

I look forward to posting questions about steps 4 and 5 asking what those mean and how to do them:

*Step 4: Add the following to “other linker flags” if they do not already appear:*

*Step 5: Add the following frameworks and libraries:*

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hum, I think it's the .pch file.

If it not exist in your Xcode project (Xcode does not create automatically this file now), create one like myproject-Prefix.pch (just an example).

And in the build settings, add your file path in `Prefix Header`

[image]

My pch file :

```
#import <Availability.h>

#ifndef __IPHONE_4_0
#warning "This project uses features only available in iOS SDK 4.0 and later."
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    #import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
    #import <SystemConfiguration/SystemConfiguration.h>
#endif
```